# Maximize sum of array intervals

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming

Given a 2D array with size N, I want to maximize `array[0][k1] + array[k1 + 1][k2] + array[k2 + 1][k3] + ... + array[kx + 1][N - 1]` for a given x. All `k` values are strictly increasing.

With small values of x (x = 2, 3, 4), a dynamic programming solution appears feasible.

However, the bound is 1 <= x, N <= 100, so I am not sure how to attempt this.

Comment: What is `x`, and what is the size of the inner N arrays?

Comment: what is 1<=x means?it can be 0?if its 0,then become `a[0][k1] + a[1][N-1]`

Comment: Maybe `x` is in `kx` means number of `k`? Can you describe more about your `dp` approach? I think using the `dp[x][n][n]` should work? O(n^4) with n = 100 is not bad.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was unclear. Pham Trung is correct, x is the number of different of k. I am also mistaken. Also, obgnaw, 1 <= x, N <= 100 is the bounds for the problem. x and N are given as input, but they are within the mentioned bounds.

Comment: How would dp[x][n][n] work? I was under the impression that you would need dp[n][n][n][n]...[n][n] for something like 100. dp[x][n][n] would be sufficient, I believe.

Comment: @j1119 see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that we are at a particular state `(ki, xi)` with `ki` is the current `k` index, `x` is the last `k` in order to give the answer for the problem, we need to try to find the maximum value we can create from this state.

We make one observation that the problem can be divided into subproblem `(ki, xi)`. As for each `(ki, xi)` state, the result is independent of previous state, we can have our formula:

- For ki == x, answer = 0
- Otherwise, `(ki, xi) = array[xi][z] + max(ki + 1, z) with z > xi`

Here is a simple pseudocode

```
int[][]dp;
boolean[][]check;
boolean maxAmount(int k, int x){
    if(k == X){
       return true;
    }
    if this state is visited {
       return check[k][x];
    } 
    boolean result = false;

    for(int i = x + 1; i < n; i++){
        if(maxAmount(k + 1, i)){
            result = true;
            dp[k][x] = max(dp[k][x], array[x][i] + dp[k + 1][i]);
        }
    }
    return check[k][x] = result;

}
```

**Note**: For the special case when we cannot find enough `k`, you need to handle it depending on the requirement, but it should be trivial.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand completely. In order to find the solution to x=2, 3, or even 100, i would just change the size of int[][][] dp and then set k = x, correct?

Comment: @j1119 yup, the key idea is for the maximum value for a state `(ki, xi, yi)` is independent of previous state, thus we can use it as our dp state

Comment: What is the special case when we cannot find enough k?

Comment: @j1119  I don't know, whether you need to return invalid if it is not acceptable, or just return whatever you have if it is ok to form an answer with less than `x` k, it depends on your specific problem.

Comment: @j1119 My answer assumed that it is ok to have less than `x` k, for your info.

Comment: There will always be a maximum and k will always be within an acceptable bound. If k is maximized and equal to N, then the array sum will be array[0][0] + array[1][1] + .. + array[N - 1][N-1]. Does this cover the special case? I am still a bit unsure.

Comment: For my purposes, there must be exactly x k. How does this affect the solution?

Comment: @j1119 see my updated answer, it returns a boolean indicate whether it can find a valid answer or not, and the value is stored in `dp` array. You should try to think harder before asking next time. There are other approaches that work too to handle this special case, but I don't know precisely about the problem, so I just proposed one

Comment: Appreciate your help, I needed that key observation!